# VSCode is ignoring .editorconfig settings for csharp files in certain folders

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, editorconfig

I am attempting to configure VSCode for use with a Unity C# project. The formatter is running, but not always following the rules in my `.editorconfig` file.

I have created a new VSCode profile and installed the following plugins:

- EditorConfig
- C#
- Unity

This automatically installed the following dependencies:

- C # Dev Kit
- IntelliCode for C# Dev Kit
- .NET Install Tool

I have a basic `.editorconfig` file in the root of my project with the following settings:

```
# EditorConfig is awesome: https://EditorConfig.org

root = true

[*]
indent_style = tab
indent_size = 4

# C# Formatting Rules
[*.cs]
csharp_new_line_before_open_brace = none
csharp_space_around_declaration_statements = ignore
csharp_space_around_binary_operators = ignore
```

In my VSCode profile `settings.json` I have set the following:

```
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "[csharp]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-dotnettools.csharp",
        "editor.codeActionsOnSave": [
            "source.organizeImports",
            "source.fixAll"
        ]
    }
```

For some reason this is not working correctly. The formatter is correctly using the `.editorconfig` settings when applied to scripts in the `/Editor/` folder, but is not using the correct options when applied to scripts in other folders, such as `/Scripts/`.

Why is VSCode ignoring my settings for csharp scripts in certain subfolders? I only have a single `.editorconfig`.

Comment: I am having the exact same issue and cannot figure out whats going on.

Comment: There is probably some extension installed which overrides the EditorConfig stuff?  (what extension have you installed (use: `code --list-extensions` to get the list of installed extensions)

Comment: As mentioned in the OP, I have created a new VSCode profile with only the listed extensions.